# HTML Form is not getting POST in php form

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, post

I am trying to create simple form and post. I have created simple form. but after submitting nothing is actually received. I have created single form.php file.

form.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    </head>
    <body>

<div class="row">
<?php

echo 'Hello World';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $key;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $value;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

?>
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<form class="form-horizontal" action="form.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tag#1</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1a" placeholder="Old Value" value="dummy">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1b" placeholder="New Value" value="dummy">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tag#2</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input2a" placeholder="Old Value" value="dummy">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input2b" placeholder="New Value" value="dummy">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tag#3</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input3a" placeholder="Old Value" value="dummy">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input3b" placeholder="New Value" value="dummy">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input4" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tag#4</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input4a" placeholder="Old Value" value="dummy">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input4b" placeholder="New Value" value="dummy">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Environment:
linux mint 16
php5

apache2 is running and "echo 'Hello World';" provided in form.php is working well.

Comment: tried checking if variable posted is available with isset($_POST['yourVar']) ? if not, your post code is wrong. check if you are posting on the page you actually want; also turn on error reporting

Comment: `<table>` tag is not opened. before `tr` and `td`

Comment: You miss name attribute in your input tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inputs need names, not id's otherwise there is no key for the $_POST array.

Answer (score 0):

Without the name attribute of the input you will be getting nothing in the $_POST as the inputs are recognised by the name.

I have replaced name for you please replace your code with mine. and you are done

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<form class="form-horizontal" action="form.php" method="post" name="post-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tag#1</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="input1a" id="input1a" placeholder="Old Value" value="dummy">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="input1b" id="input1b" placeholder="New Value" value="dummy">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tag#2</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="input2a" id="input2a" placeholder="Old Value" value="dummy">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="input2b" id="input2b" placeholder="New Value" value="dummy">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tag#3</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="input3a" id="input3a" placeholder="Old Value" value="dummy">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="input3b" id="input3b" placeholder="New Value" value="dummy">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="input4" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tag#4</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="input4a" id="input4a" placeholder="Old Value" value="dummy">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="input4b" id="input4b" placeholder="New Value" value="dummy">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="input1a" id="input1a" placeholder="Old Value" value="dummy">
</div>
```

As shown in the snippet above, you need to set the **name** attribute on the input tag for the data to be passed over when you submit a POST request to the form.